# Is there a built-in way to represent an HRESULT as a winerror.h constant such as E_FAIL?

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop, error-code

In my C# code I want to be able to log `COMException`s so that not only hex representation of `HRESULT`s (for example, `0x80004005`) is output but also the corresponding WinError.h define symbol (such as `E_FAIL`) is output.

If I call `ToString()` on the exception reference there's a hex representation only.

Is there a built-in way to get the `E_FAIL`-like human-readable constants for the `HRESULT` values inside `COMException` objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this using `COMException`'s `HResult` property

```
unchecked
{
    var msg = Marshal.GetExceptionForHR((int)0x80004005).Message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx at FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM. It returns human-readable message about passed error code.